# Date Selecting Tabs in jQuery

Tags: jquery, date, tabs

I have a set of tabs, one for each day of the week, and I would like the appropriate tab to be selected based on what day it is, using jQuery.  For instance, if the viewer sees the page on Tuesday, I would like the second tab to be the visible one when the page opens.  Could someone help get me started?  I'm pretty good with the language, so I don't need the whole thing written for me, I just don't know the best way to approach it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well to get a numeric version of the day of the week you can use this.

```
new Date().getDay();  //0=Sun, 1=Mon, ..., 6=Sat
```

Save this to a variable and use jQuery to show or hide the appropriate tab.

So, assuming the tabs have a ID of 'tab-0' for Sunday, 'tab-1' for Monday and so on, the numeric day was saved to the variable 'date' and also assuming that all the tabs are hidden by default you could use jQuery to show the tab you want.

```
$('tab-' + date).show();
```

This should show just the tab you want. Let me know if this in't what you wanted. Also some HTML code would be nice to give a more specific jQuery answer.